# Is there any way to display "scale bar" on GoogleMap?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

Is there any way to display "scale bar" on GoogleMap/FlutterApp?
I could not find any description about "scale bar" on API reference...

[image: Scale bar on the map]

Comment: How exactly you wanted to display the scale bar? Is it like an image overlay to the map? Or a dynamic one that changes value whenever you zoom in and out of the map? May I also know what you are trying to achieve with the scale bar?

Comment: I found an FR in Flutter to add a scale control to `google_maps_flutter` package. You can check it here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49179

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @jabamataro !. I'm sorry for my late response. I just want to display scale bar image overly to the map. So, FR you informed is not what I hope.